# Need support on win2003 server with Excel import using asp.net

Tags: .net, oledb

I have a web application running on win 2003 server with mssql 2005. I want to import some data through a .NET application to mssql server.

but I'm getting the error below:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.8.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I installed the this driver 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components downloaded from Microsoft.

but still the same error. Do I need to install anything else onn the server?

My server config : win 2003 x64 SP 2 with MsSql 2005 express edition

Comment: Is there more in error message or just this "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.8.0" ?!?

Comment: This could be a simple issue of x64/32-Bit driver + process. Check if your Application pool is set to x64 or 32-Bit and check which version (x64 or 32-Bit) of the OLEDB driver you have installed.

Comment: the error as below
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.8.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a driver compatibility issue.  Since you're running an x64 OS you need to either make sure the x64 driver is installed or make sure the ASP.NET application is running in x86 mode.